# Portable file/folder deletion tool with GUI (free)

Tags: portable

I'm currently looking for a data wiping tool (files, folders, partitions, whole disk) using Russian GOST P50739-95 that does not require installation (windows,and if possible linux) and has a GUI. Furthermore, it should be free and usable for commercial usage.

I found the version of erasure portable that turned out to still request an installation procedure from me though. So a dead end here.

Sadly, there are not that many options with this requirements so I hope you could provide some information about such tools and maybe also have some experience how well or not they work.